# parameter "fill_value" of method "pandas.pivot_table" not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pivoting a table with np.NaN values, those I would like to be preserved after the transformation, which is not happening at the moment.

Given the below table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7],
                   "E": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

And now applying the pivot_table:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value='HAHA').reset_index()
```

**The output I get:**

```
C   A    B     large     small
0   bar  one       0       0.0
1   bar  two       7       0.0
2   foo  one       0       0.0
3   foo  two    HAHA       0.0
```

**The output I was expecting**:

```
C   A    B     large     small
0   bar  one    HAHA      HAHA     
1   bar  two       7      HAHA     
2   foo  one    HAHA      HAHA     
3   foo  two    HAHA      HAHA
```

**Question:**
Why is the method pivot_table populating only the group "foo - two - large" and the other groups are not having their np.NaN preserved, instead having it replaced by zero?

Comment: It's working as designed; the sum of `np.NaN` elements is 0 (`df['E'].sum()==0`), it's only filling elements in your pivot that don't exist at all, which are the only ones that _would_ be nan in your output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum across all NaNs in pandas returns zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448003/sum-across-all-nans-in-pandas-returns-zero)

Comment: True, I haven't realised that the group "foo - two - large" was missing in this case. My initial thought was: since the following code "np.sum([np.nan, np.nan])" gives "nan" as result. I thought the same would happen when it's used in this method. Do you know why it does not?

Comment: As in the documentation quoted in the linked question, it looks like it's just a design decision to make that the default value in pandas. I don;t know enough to say exactly why it was defaulted to `0` instead of `nan` for output

Comment: @AfonsoSchulzAlbrecht that's a super subtle implementation decision. Basically when you pass `np.sum` as the aggfunc, pandas ignores that and instead uses getattr(Series, 'sum'). It's super hidden in the source code, but at the end of my solution I put in the table that is used to do this "dispatching". np.sum, np.nansum and sum all get dispatched to sum attribute of the DataFrame or Series. Slightly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647377/why-np-std-and-pivot-tableaggfunc-np-std-return-the-differnet-result/60647703#60647703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of how `np.sum` is treated with `groupby`. The core of `pivot_table` is a groupby followed by reshaping. We can see where the unwanted behavior arises.

```
index=['A', 'B']
columns=['C']
keys = index+columns
aggfunc=np.sum

agged = df.groupby(keys).agg(aggfunc)
#                 D    E
#A   B   C              
#bar one large  0.0  0.0
#        small  0.0  0.0
#    two large  7.0  0.0
#        small  0.0  0.0
#foo one large  0.0  0.0
#        small  0.0  0.0
#    two small  0.0  0.0
```

For `groupby` the default is that missing data are summed to 0, which will not later be considered `NaN`. However ('foo', 'two', 'large') is missing as it never had any observations in your original DataFrame. A later reshaping step gives that group, and only that group, `NaN` values.

```
table = agged
if table.index.nlevels > 1:
    # Related GH #17123
    # If index_names are integers, determine whether the integers refer
    # to the level position or name.
    index_names = agged.index.names[: len(index)]
    to_unstack = []
    for i in range(len(index), len(keys)):
        name = agged.index.names[i]
        if name is None or name in index_names:
            to_unstack.append(i)
        else:
            to_unstack.append(name)
    table = agged.unstack(to_unstack)

print(table)
#            D           E      
#C       large small large small
#A   B                          
#bar one   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
#    two   7.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
#foo one   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
#    two   NaN   0.0   NaN   0.0
```

---

So how do you get your desired behavior? You need to set `dropna=False`. Pandas is also clever and tries to ["dispatch"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#dispatching-to-instance-methods) most of the basic operations to their optimized equivalents. We need to use a lambda to avoid that.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], 
               aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x),
               dropna=False,
               fill_value='HAHA')

        large small
A   B              
bar one  HAHA  HAHA
    two     7  HAHA
foo one  HAHA  HAHA
    two  HAHA  HAHA
```

---

We can see that `sum`, `np.nansum` and `np.sum` all get aliased to the `Series.sum` attribute. The lambda is the simplest way to avoid that.

```
[func for func, attr in pd.DataFrame()._cython_table.items() if attr == 'sum']
#[<function sum>, <function numpy.sum>, <function numpy.nansum>]
```